# Google signIn doesn't wok in a non UIViewController

Tags: swift3, google-signin

I need to authenticate users using Google-SignIn SDK,
It worked successfully when I used it in a class UIViewcontroller class.
but I need to implement signIn method in a separate class what should I do to work successfully? 
my GoogleLogin class is looks like

```
import Foundation
import GoogleSignIn

class GoogleLogin:NSObject, LoginAuthProtocol, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate{

    weak var googleView: UIViewController!

    init(view: UIViewController) {
        super.init()
        googleView = view

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "1017499022947-4d73nf64.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    }

    func login() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if error != nil{
            print("*****error \(error.localizedDescription) ******")
            return
        }
        print(user.profile.email)
    }

    func sign(inWillDispatch signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: Error!) {

    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!) {
        googleView.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
        googleView.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

when I need to start login I call login() method from my root viewController and path self as a parameter

```
GoogleLogin(view: self).login()
```

but nothing happen after call!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is I initialize and call login at the same time in

```
GoogleLogin(view: self).login()
```

it should be

```
let googleLogin = GoogleLogin(view: self)
googleLogin.login()
```